# jQuery ui dialog modal remove link dotted border around image

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I've got a dialog popup that I cannot get the border around a linked imaged to disappear.

http://www.littlecurryshop.com/home-test-2-1

I can't change the ui css file as its in squarespace and I just have to link it in the head of the document.

I can add custom css but I cannot make this border disappear!

The code is sloppy because of a lot of fiddling but here it is:

html

## Biju's Little Curry Shop
 Now has an online store

```
    <p>
      <br />
      <a href="/store" class="link">Check out the selection now</a>
    </p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
//Popup
.ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none !important;}
.ui-widget-overlay {background: #000 !important; opacity: .6 !important;}
.no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  display: none;
}
.ui-widget-content .image {text-decoration:none !important;border-width:   0px !important;}
#popUp {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border: solid 4px rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(227,177,59,.8) !important;
}
#popUp img {width: 14%;}
#popUp h1 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}
#popUp h1 span:first-child {
  background-color: #375b89;
  color: #e2b23c;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
#popUp h1 span:last-child {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #333;
}
#popUp a {border-width:0 !important;text-decoration: none;}
#popUp .image img {background-color: #fff; border: solid 6px  #c1282d;border-radius: 100%; padding: 20px 20px 30px;width: 30%;height:   auto;}
#popUp .link{
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #375b89;
  border: solid 2px #375b89 !important;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  animation: unonline forwards 1s;
  -webkit-animation: uonline forwards 1s;
}
#popUp .link:hover {
  animation: online forwards 1s;
  -webkit-animation: online forwards 1s;
}
@keyframes online {
  from {background-color: transparent;}
  to {background-color: #375b89;color: #fff;}
}
@keyframes unonline {
  from {background-color: #375b89}
  to {background-color: transparent; color: #c1282d}
}
#popUp .close {float:right;}
#popUp i {font-size: 28px;}
#popUp h2 {color: orange;}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var wW = $(window).width();
var w = wW * .9;

  $('#popUp').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false, 
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    width: w,
    height: "auto",
    show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 800},
    hide: {effect: 'fade', duration: 500}
 });
  setTimeout(openPopup, 2500);
  function openPopup(){
    $('#popUp').dialog('open');
    $('#header').hide();
  }
});

$('.close').click(function(){
  $('#popUp').dialog('close');
  $('#header').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the image is producing the dotted boarder. Try adding this line in your script.

```
$('#yui_3_17_2_1_1451624877239_290').css('outline','none');
```

Hope it helps.